# Domain Class Field Type not Getting Mapped to Spring Data ElasticSearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a Domain Class of Books
I use this for hibernate and elasticsearch both.

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.DateFormat;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
@Document(indexName="booksearchserver",type="book")

public class Book {

@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
@Id
@Column(name="bookIsbn")
@Field(type = FieldType.Integer, store = true)
private long bookIsbn;

@Column(name="bookTitle")
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
private String bookTitle;

@Column(name="authorId")
@Field(type = FieldType.Integer, store = true)
private int bookAuthorId;

@Column(name="bookLanguage")
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
private String bookLanguage;

@Column(name="bookPublisherId")
@Field(type = FieldType.Integer, store = true)
private short bookPublisherId;

@Column(name="bookReleaseDate")
@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true, format=DateFormat.date)
private Date bookReleaseDate;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="bookNoOfChapters")
private short bookNoOfChapters;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="bookNoOfPages")
private short bookNoOfPages;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="bookNoOfWords")
private int bookWordCount;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="bookPrecededByIsbn" )
private long bookPrecededBy;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="bookFollowedByIsbn")
private long bookFollowedBy;


@Column(name="bookDescription")
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true )
private String bookDescription;

@JsonIgnore
@Column(name="bookCoverImage")
private String bookCover;
```

I have a repository Class

```
package co.in.searchServer.repository;

org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

import co.in.searchServer.model.Book;

public interface ESDao extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book,Long> {
Iterable<Book> search(QueryBuilder arg0);
Book findBybookIsbn(long isbn);
<S extends Book> S index(S arg0);
}
```

On doing a

```
    GET booksearchserver/book/_mapping
    {
       "booksearchserver": {
          "mappings": {
             "book": {
                "properties": {
                   "bookAuthorId": {
                      "type": "integer",
                      "store": true
                   },
                   "bookDescription": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "store": true
                   },
                   "bookIsbn": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "index": "not_analyzed"
                   },
                   "bookLanguage": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "store": true
                   },
                   "bookPublisherId": {
                      "type": "integer",
                      "store": true
                   },
                   "bookReleaseDate": {
                      "type": "date",
                      "store": true,
                      "format": "date"
                   },
                   "bookTitle": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "store": true
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

I have the Following Problems:

1. the ***"bookIsbn"*** Field does not have the long data type as specified in elasticsearch.
2. I have to use the @JsonIgnore to completely stop the field from being stored    in elastic search.

I Have tried putting mapping using the elasticsearchTemplate Class as well.

I think the Field Annotations are not working.

please provide some experiences and solutions

Comment: I think that's because the `bookIsbn` field is also flag as the ID field and ID field must be strings in ES.

Comment: I am using **long** for 'bookIsbn' when mapping the fields through sense and it is getting mapped as a long over there

Comment: Yes, if you create the mapping manually through Sense, that makes sense. However, here you're delegating this task to Spring Data and at some point it might decide to change the type to string since you also flagged that field as `@Id`

Comment: I Tried using the @Id and i think that this annotation converts the field to string even if we specify the field type. Thanks for the help mate.